# JQuery - Detect if element is fully in viewport

Tags: jquery, plugins, viewport

I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fpatik%2Fwithin-viewport&ei=yTZkUoiPKYfpigKv2oDoBw&usg=AFQjCNHjl2WKy5gm7o7mI07y0U5P_MmcyQ&sig2=MmTdf-WOnV5aGKW3p2QiyQ&bvm=bv.54934254,d.cGE) to execute an animation when if an element is fully visible in the viewport; kind of like a lightbox effect. It somewhat responsive ... but moreso not. Not sure if I'm using the right approach. Any ideas?

```
$(window).bind("resize mousewheel scroll scrollStop", function() {
if($(".tailor .content").is(":within-viewport")) {
    $(".tailor").animate({opacity:'1.0'}, 900, 'easeInOutQuart');
}
else {
    $(".tailor").animate({opacity:'0.8'}, 900, 'easeInOutQuart');
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use to detect when an element is fully visible then do whatever I want with it:

```
// Create jQuery Method
jQuery.fn.isFullyVisible = function(){

var win = $(window);

var viewport = {
    top : win.scrollTop(),
    left : win.scrollLeft()
};
viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

var elemtHeight = this.height();// Get the full height of current element
elemtHeight = Math.round(elemtHeight);// Round it to a whole number

var bounds = this.offset();// Coordinates of current element
bounds.top = bounds.top + elemtHeight;
bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

}

//Usage:
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if( $('.tailor .content').isFullyVisible() ){
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks mate.

Comment: @JibuJames no problem! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to use a plug-in for that :-) This should work easily;

```
var el = $('.tailor .content');
var $window = $(window);
var isInFrame = false;

$window.on('scroll', function() {
    if((el.offset().top < ($window.scrollTop + $window.height())) && ((el.offset().top + el.heigt()) > $window.scrollTop))
    {
        if(!isInFrame) 
        {
            isInFrame = true;
            el.animate({opacity:'1.0'}, 900, 'easeInOutQuart');
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if(isInFrame) 
        {
            isInFrame = false;
            el.animate({opacity:'0.8'}, 900, 'easeInOutQuart');
        }
    }
});
```

You'll need to keep track if your element is already in frame; or else it'll keep resetting the animation every time you scroll.